# MVVM interaction drop trigger

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a ListView that I need to function as a drop target. I have added the following trigger

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Drop">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ItemsDroppedCommand}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding ???}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

The problem is though I dont know how to get the dropped items. What should go in the CommandParameter binding?

If I do a drop handler in code behind I get a DragEventArgs parameter that enables me to get the files dropped. Is there a way to get this?

If this is the wrong approach please feel free to suggest alternatives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing an event's arguments to a Command through binding isn't supported out of the box but *can* be achieved through [a workaround](http://weblogs.asp.net/alexeyzakharov/archive/2010/03/24/silverlight-commands-hacks-passing-eventargs-as-commandparameter-to-delegatecommand-triggered-by-eventtrigger.aspx).

However, I would recommend you to use the [EventToCommand](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2009/11/05/mvvm-light-toolkit-v3-alpha-2-eventtocommand-behavior.aspx) behavior available in [MVVM Light](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/), which enables exactly this scenario:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Drop">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding ItemsDroppedCommand}"
                            PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. While investigating I also found this [link](http://weblogs.asp.net/alexeyzakharov/archive/2010/03/24/silverlight-commands-hacks-passing-eventargs-as-commandparameter-to-delegatecommand-triggered-by-eventtrigger.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+AlexeyZakharov+(Alexey+Zakharovs+Blog))

Answer (score 2):

please take a look on this thread [MVVM Passing EventArgs As Command Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205472/mvvm-passing-eventargs-as-command-parameter)

In this thread will help you solve the problem.
I hope this help.