# how to pass argument to the method present in event trigger wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Actually, I'm trying to pass the name of the word document in the method UpdateWord(object obj) present in the ViewModel of the Xaml file. So that it will open the word document.

```
<Button Content="Show Word" Width="100" Height="25" Margin="128,70,22,37">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <si:CallDataMethod Method="UpdateWord"/>     
                <si:SetProperty TargetName="LayoutRoot" 
        PropertyName="Background" Value="PaleGoldenrod"/>
     </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

ViewModel :

```
public void UpdateWord(Object obj)
{

   //Do Something ..... ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do like this

```
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding UpdateWord}"
            PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
```

you can refer this post for more deatil : http://weblogs.asp.net/alexeyzakharov/silverlight-commands-hacks-passing-eventargs-as-commandparameter-to-delegatecommand-triggered-by-eventtrigger

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of doing this, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205472/mvvm-passing-eventargs-as-command-parameter/28410798#28410798):

1. Using WPF Tools. Easiest

Add Namespaces:

- System.Windows.Interactivitiy
- Microsoft.Expression.Interactions

XAML:

```
<Window>
    xmlns:wi="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions">

    <wi:Interaction.Triggers>
        <wi:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
            <ei:CallMethodAction
                TargetObject="{Binding}"
                MethodName="ShowCustomer"/>
        </wi:EventTrigger>
    </wi:Interaction.Triggers>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public void ShowCustomer()
{
    // Do something.
}
```

2. Using MVVMLight. Most difficult but best practice

Install GalaSoft NuGet package.

[image]

Get the namespaces:

- System.Windows.Interactivity
- GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform

XAML

```
<Window>
    xmlns:wi="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    xmlns:cmd="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight">

    <wi:Interaction.Triggers>
       <wi:EventTrigger EventName="Navigated">
           <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding NavigatedEvent}"
               PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
       </wi:EventTrigger>
    </wi:Interaction.Triggers>
</Window>
```

Code With Delegates: [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx)

You must get the Prism MVVM NuGet package for this.

[image]

```
using Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Commands;

// With params.
public DelegateCommand<string> CommandOne { get; set; }
// Without params.
public DelegateCommand CommandTwo { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Must initialize the DelegateCommands here.
    CommandOne = new DelegateCommand<string>(executeCommandOne);
    CommandTwo = new DelegateCommand(executeCommandTwo);
}

private void executeCommandOne(string param)
{
    // Do something here.
}

private void executeCommandTwo()
{
    // Do something here.
}
```

Code Without DelegateCommand: [Source](http://gotoanswer.com/?q=reuse%20code%20for%20RelayCommand)

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    CommandOne = new RelayCommand<string>(executeCommandOne);
    CommandTwo = new RelayCommand(executeCommandTwo);
}

public RelayCommand<string> CommandOne { get; set; }

public RelayCommand CommandTwo { get; set; }

private void executeCommandOne(string param)
{
    // Do something here.
}

private void executeCommandTwo()
{
    // Do something here.
}
```

3. Using [Telerik EventToCommandBehavior](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/common-event-to-command-behavior). You'll have to download it's [NuGet Package](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/installation-and-deployment/installing-telerik-ui-on-your-computer/installation-installing-from-nuget-wpf). It's an option.

XAML:

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <telerek:EventToCommandBehavior
         Command="{Binding DropCommand}"
         Event="Drop"
         PassArguments="True" />
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

Code:

```
public ActionCommand<DragEventArgs> DropCommand { get; private set; }

this.DropCommand = new ActionCommand<DragEventArgs>(OnDrop);

private void OnDrop(DragEventArgs e)
{
    // Do Something
}
```

Comment: are any of these stock .net? i think they are prism and telerik. and your third example does not pass any arguments?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are as Idk how to work with Prism and I have no idea what telerik is. These are just ways I found off of stack overflow and other sites that I thought other developers might find handy and I do find it handy myself so I put it all in one answer.

Comment: Third one passes binding, which is whomever it is inheriting from.

Comment: then maybe you can provide the namespaces for `ei` `wi` `beh` and even `i` because without them this is really hard to use

Comment: @Julien thank you for the comments. The code is now updated. I realized one of them was using MVVM Light, Prism is optional and Telerak was one of the examples as well. All namespaces and NuGet packages are added.