# Command binding using ViewModel method

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm using some application commands like New, Open, etc and I'd like to have their executed and CanExecute handlers in the viewmodel but I'm having trouble with it and I can't seem to find anything that solves this. I have a commandBinding like this and I have a NewCommand_Executed meghot in the viewmodel, which is the datacontext of my window.

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.New" Executed="{Binding NewCommand_Executed}" CanExecute="Default_CanExecute" />
...
```

However, I get a parse exception for this with an inner exception saying:
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeEventInfo' to type 'System.Reflection.MethodInfo'. Can someone explain what I am missing or if there is a way to achieve what I'm trying?

Comment: I think your commands in code need to be of type `ICommand`, and it sounds like you have them as methods instead.

Comment: Take a look here. The second implementation with delegate commands will allow you to use CanExecute. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28448319/how-to-pass-argument-to-the-method-present-in-event-trigger-wpf/28469215#28469215

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the MVVM pattern, you should consider adopting delegate commands in place of CommandBindings.
You can find [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx) a tutorial about MVVM. The section, which talks about [Commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx#sec10), can help you.