# Cast ListBox item back to its Collection type

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

In my XAML I have two tabs, the first contains a ListBox bound to ObservableCollection objects, called ParameterFilesList, and the second a ListBox bound to ObservableCollection objects, called CalcFilesList.

```
    <UserControl x:Class="Sym.VisualStudioExtension.Engines.TAEngineView"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     xmlns:behaviours="clr-namespace:Sym.VisualStudioExtension"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sym.VisualStudioExtension"
     local:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="700" d:DesignWidth="400">
<Grid>
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="490" Margin="19,44,-36,-234" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="317">
    <TabItem Header="Parameter Files">
        <ListBox Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding ParameterFilesList}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                    
        </ListBox>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Calc Files">
        <ListBox Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding CalcFilesList}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                   
        </ListBox>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
<Label x:Name="label" Content="{Binding Path=Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="367
       " BorderThickness="2"/>

</Grid>
```

When I double-click on an item, I want to open the underlying file that the name in the list displays. First, I need to get the list item back to the Parameter/CalcFile object.

Currently, I handle the double-click in the code-behind:

```
private void ListBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dynamic viewModel = DataContext;
        viewModel.OpenOnDoubleClick(sender, e);
    }
```

Then my idea was to determine the Parameter or CalcFile type in the ViewModel's OpenOnDoubleClick method, but I don't know how to do it. I get cast errors.

**It seems that the sender is the ListBoxItem, but how do I cast it to Parameter/CalcFile in the ViewModel?**

I don't actually want to bring the Parameter/CalcFile into the xaml.cs file. I would prefer to keep that separate from the model, and just use it as a intermediary to handle and pass the double-click event on to the viewmodel.

Oh yes, and I guess I could have different event handlers for the different tabs, so one for the Parameter list and one for the CalcFile list, so that I have `ParameterListBox_MouseDoubleClick` and `CalcFileListBox_MouseDoubleClick` and then two different methods in the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It seems that the sender is the ListBoxItem, but how do I cast it to Parameter/CalcFile in the ViewModel?

Cast the DataContext of the ListBox item to your type. Something like this:

```
    private void ListBox_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListBoxItem lbi = sender as ListBoxItem;
        CalcFile clickedCalcFile = lbi.DataContext as CalcFile;
        if(clickedCalcFile != null)
        {
            var viewModel = DataContext as YourViewModelType;
            viewModel.OpenOnDoubleClick(clickedCalcFile);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the sender is the ListBoxItem, but how do I cast it to Parameter/CalcFile in the ViewModel?

try (sender as ListBoxItem).DataContext

and for MVVM,

use EventToCommand(interactivity) and you can find invoke command with parameters from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205472/mvvm-passing-eventargs-as-command-parameter),