# Inner GroupBox does not swallow the Interactivity event

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a `GroupBox` within a parent `GroupBox`. Both of them have their own

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
  <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
     <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ...}"  />
  </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

When I press the inner `GroupBox` it fires its own `Command` and then the parent `Command` is also triggered.

How do I prevent that? How do I make the inner `GroupBox` swallow the event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use another implementation of TriggerAction that supports passing the event args as a command parameter to the command, for example the `EventToCommand` class in the [MvvmLight](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight/) library:

```
<GroupBox Header="Outer" xmlns:mvvm="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OuterCommand}"  />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock>...</TextBlock>
        <GroupBox Header="Inner" Grid.Row="1">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <mvvm:EventToCommand Command="{Binding InnerCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"  />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <TextBlock>inner...</TextBlock>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</GroupBox>
```

---

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {

        OuterCommand = new RelayCommand(arg => true, (arg)=> { MessageBox.Show("outer"); });
        InnerCommand = new RelayCommand(arg => true, 
            (arg) => 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("inner");
                MouseButtonEventArgs mbea = arg as MouseButtonEventArgs;
                if (mbea != null)
                    mbea.Handled = true;
            });
    }

    public RelayCommand OuterCommand { get; }

    public RelayCommand InnerCommand { get; }
}
```

The ugly thing with this solution is that the view model has a dependency upon the view related `MouseButtonEventArgs` type though. If you don't like this you can implement your own behaviour as suggested by @adabyron here:

[MVVM Passing EventArgs As Command Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6205472/mvvm-passing-eventargs-as-command-parameter)

Then you could set the Handled property of the MouseButtonEventArgs directly in the behaviour instead of passing it along to the view model.

Comment: that's the solution!

Comment: If my command already looks like this `return new RelayCommand<MyOwnArgs>(this.OnInnerCommand);`, how would I also pass the `MouseButtonEventArgs`? Also, I think you meant to put `arg => true` in second position, if you are referring to the `CanExecute`.

Comment: You can only pass a single command so then you would need to implement a custom behaviour or handle the MouseLeftButtonDown event of the inner GroupBox in the code-behind of the view and invoke the command of the view model from there after you have set the Handled property to true.