# MVVM Pass key as CommandParameter in KeyBinding of Window

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, inputbinding

Is there a way to pass entered key as command parameter in InputBindings of Window? I tried achive this by code below, but it isn't working.

```
     <KeyBinding x:Name="KeyBinding" Command="{Binding ChoosePackageSizeFromKeyboard}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=KeyBinding, Path=Key}" />
```

I don't wanna create binding for every key I wanna use, cause depending of condition it will be beetween 1 and 5 keys. Any ideas how to pass it to command?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to use `KeyBinding` the way you want to. You have to provide a value for the `Key` property for it to work.

What you could do instead is handle the `KeyUp` (or similar) event on the `Window`. If you want to bind on a `Command`, you can take a look at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6205643/65060) for more details on how to pass the `EventArgs` to the command.