# How select multiple rows in WPF DataGrid without holding Ctrl Key?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

How do I select multiple rows in a datagrid on mouse click without using a control key or check boxes?

Comment: You can simulate the Ctrl key in code.

Comment: Cant you already do that by dragging mouse over rows to select them? But Fragmented selection (Extended Selection) is possible only with Ctrl Key though. May be you can use click of the MouseWheelButton for extended selection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF Datagrid Multiple Selection without CTRL or Space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053526/wpf-datagrid-multiple-selection-without-ctrl-or-space)

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053526/wpf-datagrid-multiple-selection-without-ctrl-or-space/43091400#43091400) (like MVVM) solution will solve your problem.

Answer (score -3):

You can try out SelectionMode="Extended".